# Disable all Sundays except one in jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to set up jQuery UI datepicker for my clients' websites, and it needs to hide certain days, as well as all Sundays EXCEPT mothering Sunday. Currently my code, borrowed heavily from another answer runs as:

```
        function nonWorkingDates(date){
            var day = date.getDay(), Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6;
            var closedDates = [[02,24,2012],[03,14,2012],[03,15,2012],[03,20,2012],[03,21,2012],[03,23,2012],[03,26,2012],[03,27,2012]];
            var closedDays = [[Sunday]];  
            var mothersDay = [[04,18,2012]];  
            for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {
                if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {
                    return [false];
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < closedDates.length; i++) {
                if (date.getMonth() == closedDates[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == closedDates[i][1] && date.getFullYear() == closedDates[i][2]) {
                    return [false];
                }
            }
            return [true];
        }       
        <%-- Load jQuery UI Calendar --%>
        $(function() {
            jQuery("#calendar1").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });         
        });
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add another condition for "special" dates before your other logic:

```
function nonWorkingDates(date) {
    var day = date.getDay(),
        Sunday = 0,
        Monday = 1,
        Tuesday = 2,
        Wednesday = 3,
        Thursday = 4,
        Friday = 5,
        Saturday = 6;
    var closedDates = [
        [02, 24, 2012],
        [03, 14, 2012],
        [03, 15, 2012],
        [03, 20, 2012],
        [03, 21, 2012],
        [03, 23, 2012],
        [03, 26, 2012],
        [03, 27, 2012]];

    var closedDays = [[Sunday]];
    var mothersDay = [03, 18, 2012];  

    /* Mother's day check: */
    if (date.getMonth() === mothersDay[0] - 1 &&
        date.getDate() === mothersDay[1] &&
        date.getFullYear() === mothersDay[2]) {

            return [true];
    }                                 

    for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {
        if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {
            return [false];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < closedDates.length; i++) {
        if (date.getMonth() == closedDates[i][0] - 1 &&
            date.getDate() == closedDates[i][1] &&
            date.getFullYear() == closedDates[i][2]) {

            return [false];
        }
    }
    return [true];
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6wwSn/